# rails Nested form fields are not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a book consultation form with following fields from two models

User Model 
 - first_name
 - last_name
 - email
 - contact_number

Message Model

- :message_text

The desired form rendered should be presenting the user all the User Model fields along with a text area which would be :message_text for the Message Model.

**The code of User Model is**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :messages

  validates :first_name , presence: true
  validates :last_name , presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :contact_number,presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages
end
```

**The Code of Message Model**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :message_text, presence: true
    belongs_to :user , :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key  => 'id'

end
```

**The index controller of User which renders the form looks like**

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  @user = User.new
  @user.messages.build
end
```

**The view file looks like**

```
<%= form_for(@user)  do |f| %>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :first_name %>
            <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :last_name %>
            <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.text_field :email %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :contact_number %>
            <%= f.text_field :contact_number %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        **the fields_for does not get rendered at all into the HTML** 
            <%= f.fields_for :messages do |ff| %>
                <%= ff.label :message_text %>
                <%= ff.text_field :message_text %>
            <% end %>
        </div>

        <div class="btn primary-btn">
            <%= f.submit 'Book Free Consultation'%>
        </div>
```

All other fields get rendered. Can anybody please help me in spotting the mistake . Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you add the associations after the model generation and then forget to migrate the database?

Comment: No i have completed the migration and also seeded some data and tested the association in rails console . It is working but not rendering in html

Answer (score 0):

your migration file should be like below

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :contact_number
    end
  end
end

class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:messages) do |t|
      t.string :message_text
      t.references :user, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :contact_number

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.text :message_text
      t.references :user
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

Comment: plz do index: true for t.refernces :user

Comment: Sorry no luck it is not working . However if it in the index action i create a new message object @message = Message.new and in the view of the index i try to render the nested form like <%= f.fields_for(@message) do |ff| %> <%= ff.input :message_text , label: "Your Message", as: :text %> <% end %>. It works not with <%= f.fields_for :messages do |ff| %>.